# Profanity check

Tags: apex

I have a multiselect picklist in my grandparent object.

I have a text field in my object.

Whenever user enters text into this text field ,and after saving i need to check whether my text contains the values defined in picklist

This is mainly for a profanity check .

what is the best way to do this

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a work flow rule on my object, from my object you can access grand parent fields.

Comment: can i check whether my text contains values(or variations of values) in multiselect picklist using formulas in workflow?

Comment: did you tried isPickVal() in your rule criteria

Comment: ISPICKVAL is to check whether a value has been selected in a 'picklist'.This is a multipicklist and what i want to do is to check whether my text field contains values in multipicklist

Comment: Contains(text,cmptext), this function is used for comparing my object text field and my grandparent text, it will return true or false, you can combine this with IF condition ,hoe this helps you.